# selenium wait for flash page load (document.ready)

Tags: c#, selenium, flash, selenium-webdriver

I want to make screenshot on webpage which is written in flash

For that I have this code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
...
// I'm clicking on button whicch opens new browser window
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("click_me")).Click();

Thread.Sleep(1500);
//switch to new window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

//maximize it
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

//wait for load
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

//and then take screenshot
Screenshot sc = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

sc.SaveAsFile(String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), Guid.NewGuid(), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png), ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

Here works everything but wait for load. It takes a screenshot of loading screen. What can i do?

Comment: if you don't want to use any other frameworks, just add some code to wait for a particular text on webpage before taking screenshot. For ex: try to search whether the particular text is visible or not then go ahead with screenshot.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar but it's flash not html. so how can I do that?

Comment: Don't we have a single HTML element to search for ?

Comment: there is body/div/object. these tags are loaded fast but content inside object tag (swf) not

Answer (score 0):

```
//wait for load     
WaitForLoading(driver);

private void WaitForLoading(IWebDriver driver)
{
    var javascriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    _wait.Until(webDriver => javascriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").ToString() == "complete");
}
```

Comment: `private WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`

Comment: thanks for answer but anyway I'm getting loading screen. So html is loaded but flash loading dialog still appears

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976105/selenium-can-i-test-if-a-page-loaded-a-flash-app-ie-a-swf-properly  here is exactly your problem solved

Comment: do you know in which package is `FlashSelenium` class? can't find it yet

Comment: oh it's `dll` found it here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/flash-selenium/downloads

Comment: I've downloaded this dll https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/flash-selenium/FlashSelenium.dll, added it to my solution and I can see that `FlashSelenium` class here

Comment: thanks and I think last question. what will be first parameter for FlashSelenium class? I haven't any selenium object.

Comment: it requires ISelenium, but this interface is no longer supported https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_Selenium_ISelenium.htm

Comment: so it seems I can't use that